# Fuzzy Search in Solr

Tags: solr, fuzzy-search

I am working on a a fuzzy query using Solr, which goes over a repository of data which could have misspelled words or abbreviated words.  For example the repository could have a name with words "Hlth" (abbreviated form of the word 'Health').

1. If I do a fuzzy search  for `Name:'Health'~0.35`  I get results with word 'Health' but not 'Hlth'.
2. If I do a fuzzy search for `Name:'Hlth'~0.35` I get records with names 'Health' and 'Hlth'.

I would like to get first query to work.  In my bussiness use-case, I would have to use the clean data to query for all the misspelled or abbreviated words.

Could someone please help and throw some light on why #1 fuzzy search is not working and if there are any other ways of achieving the same.

Answer (score 9):

You use fuzzy query in a wrong way.

According to what Mike McCandless saying (http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/03/lucenes-fuzzyquery-is-100-times-faster.html):

> FuzzyQuery matches terms "close" to a specified base term: you specify an allowed maximum edit distance, and any terms within that edit distance from the base term (and, then, the docs containing those terms) are matched.
>
> The QueryParser syntax is term~ or term~N, where N is the maximum
>   allowed number of edits (for older releases N was a confusing float
>   between 0.0 and 1.0, which translates to an equivalent max edit
>   distance through a tricky formula).
>
> FuzzyQuery is great for matching proper names: I can search for
>   mcandless~1 and it will match mccandless (insert c), mcandles (remove
>   s), mkandless (replace c with k) and a great many other "close" terms.
>   With max edit distance 2 you can have up to 2 insertions, deletions or
>   substitutions. The score for each match is based on the edit distance
>   of that term; so an exact match is scored highest; edit distance 1,
>   lower; etc.

So you need to write queries like this - Health~2

Comment: doesn't work! I wanted to match Parkway with Pkwy and vice versa. Parkway~2 matches only Parkway and Pkwy~2 matches only Pkwy

Comment: @Mysterion : FuzzyQuery is not working why? it tried = "who is johnn"~0.2

Answer (score 3):

You write: "I wanted to match Parkway with Pkwy"

Parkway and Pkwy have an edit distance of 3. You could achieve this by subbing in "~3" for "~2" from the first response, but Solr fuzzy matching is not recommended for values greater than 2 for performance reasons.

I think the best way to approach your problem would be to generate a context-specific dictionary of synonyms and do query-time expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Using phonetic filters may solve your problem.

Please consider looking at the following
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-PhoneticFilter

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Phonetic+Matching

Hope this helps.